# Convergence depending on step

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Lets say I have a sequence of maps $a_n : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $a : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n = a$$ uniformly. Now I now that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $N$ such that $\forall N\geq n$ 
$$\lVert a_n - a \rVert < \epsilon.$$ 
Can I name the $\epsilon$ explicitly depending on $n$ such as e.g. 
$$\lVert a_n - a \rVert < \frac{1}{n} ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is too much to ask.

For example if you let $\epsilon =1/10$ you may or may not have $||a_{10}-a||<\frac {1}{10}$ depending on your functions.

In other words we do not have control over the sequence of functions to make $||a_n-a||<\frac {1}{n}$ happen.

Comment: I thought so :( Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes  you can, since $||a_n - a||< \epsilon$ holds for every $\epsilon >0$.  So u can take $\epsilon = 1/n$.

Comment: This holds for all $n$ exceeding a certain $N$ right?